# Maximum amount of objects in NSArray

Tags: cocoa, nsarray

What is the largest amount of objects I can put in my NSArray?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The NSArray initWithCapacity method, takes an unsigned int as an argument.  So whatever the maximum value of an unsigned int is on your platform may be the theoretical limit.  However the actual limit is more likely to depend on the amount of memory you have available.

Comment: `NSUInteger`, not `unsigned int`. On 64-bit architectures, `unsigned int` is still 4 bytes, whereas `NSUInteger`—which is what NSArray uses since Leopard—is 8.

Comment: It is not correct to assume that the maximum number of objects NSUIntegerMax. As jsmp points out, NSArray uses NSNotFound. NSNotFound is defined as NSIntegerMax which is less than NSUInteger. This implies that the max number of objects is NSIntegerMax-1. I would test this as Dave Delong suggests but I run out if memory!

Comment: Hope you have enough RAM to hold 180 times as much information as Lt. Cmd. Data! http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?dataset=&i=(1*(2%5E64)+%2B+8+%2B+8)+bytes

Answer (score 11):

Have you tried to find out?  ;)

```
NSMutableArray * a = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSUInteger i = 0;
@try {
  while (1) {
     [a addObject:@"hi"];
     i++;
  }
} @catch (NSException * e) {
  NSLog(@"added %llu elements", i);
}
```

Comment: Delong while am trying your idea and find out size limit ,that app crashes and got error as Program received signal: “0”. Data Formatters temporarily unavailable, will re-try after a 'continue'. (Unknown error loading shared library "/Developer/usr/lib/libXcodeDebuggerSupport.dylib")

Comment: you ran out of memory. just log what i is at each iteration and let it crash, the last log will tell you how many you could get.  By the way, your test tells you the size is only limited to memory.

Answer (score 5):

In most cases concerning the upper limits of programming structures and the like: 
"If you have to ask, you're probably doing it wrong" - TheDailyWTF.com

Answer (score 3):

Probably more than your RAM can handle.

Answer (score 3):

**NSNotFound** is defined as **NSIntegerMax** (this value changes if you are on a 32bit or 64bit system)

**NSNotFound** is also the result you get when you do a

> [nsarray indexOfObject:obj]

and no object is found.

If you do not run out of space/memory I would say that this would be your limit.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/Reference/reference.html

Answer (score 1):

NSArray is a container of pointers to other objects. Its maximum capacity is defined by [NSUInteger](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_DataTypes/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSUInteger) (on the latest versions of the available OSs):

> When building 32-bit applications,
>   NSUInteger is a 32-bit unsigned
>   integer. A 64-bit application treats
>   NSUInteger as a 64-bit unsigned
>   integer

Therefore, whatever the size of NSUInteger is on a given device is the maximum number of object pointers it can contain. However, as Eimantas alluded to in his answer, this isn't the same as "how many objects can it hold" because this depends on available memory. You may not have enough RAM available at a given moment to allocate an array with six billion slots for example ...