# Is there any limit to add object in NSMutableArray..?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsmutablearray

Recently I'm working on project which requires a large no. of object should be added to an NSMutableArray.

I'm little bit confusing how much object we can add in **NSMutableArray**..?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think there is no effective limit (you will run out of memory before reaching it).

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS how large can an NSSet/NSArray/NSDictionary be?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10869049/ios-how-large-can-an-nsset-nsarray-nsdictionary-be)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably all dependent on memory. Older generation devices get a smaller share of RAM (memory) to use than newer devices for the apps they run. Therefore, the limit is probably lower on older devices than newer ones. That said, it probably can't be pinpointed to a specific number (unless I am mistaken).

Rather, what you should try to do is figure out if you can handle memory better here so you're not worried about a size limit :)

**EDIT**
From Steffen Itterheim's "Learn Cocos2D Game Development With iOS 5", based on the installed memory of a device, here are some rough estimates of the amount of memory apps can expect to work with:

128MB Installed => 35-40MB available, memory warnings at 20-25MB;

256MB Installed => 120-150MB available, mem warning at 80-90MB;

512 MB Installed => 340-370MB available, mem warning at 260-300MB.

Of course these are rough estimates, but depending on the device you can obviously see that the size of an NSMutableArray depends on the available memory