# What is the range of NSArray

Tags: iphone, xcode

I am developing a reading words app, the words are got from paragraph, I want NSArray range to store maximum words, to help find size of NSArray

```
 NSString *string=@"Some people say that Apple will fit an A5 chip in iphone5 with a clocking speed in range of 1.2 0r 1.5 GHz with 1 GB Ram. It is also anticipated that it will b fire proof phone.  ";
    NSArray *piecesOfOriginalString = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
    NSLog(@"%i",piecesOfOriginalString.count);
```

It is my simple example.

Here, the problem is how to find maximum allowable size of array???

Comment: I don't see a question here.  Your example code finds the size of the array correctly using the `count` property.

Comment: range of int=(–2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647)                         range of nsarray=.....?

Answer (score 4):

In theory, the maximum size of an NSArray is shown by the type of its `-count` method, which is `NSUInteger`. For iOS, that's equivalent to an `unsigned long`, so the maximum count is 4,294,967,295.

In practice, you're limited by the memory of the device and the sizes of the objects in the array.

Comment: An unsigned long on the iPhone (32 bits) is 4,294,967,295.  What you gave is the positive range for a signed long.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to fine the size then
    http://lapcatsoftware.com/blog/2006/10/10/filling-an-nsmutablearray/

then read one time this

[Maximum amount of objects in NSArray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155462/maximum-amount-of-objects-in-nsarray)

You'll either get 4 or 8, depending on if you are on a 32 or 64 bit system.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking: "how many elements do I have in this array," what you wrote should work fine (though the "count" property returns an NSUInteger, so you should use the %li String Format Specifier, instead of %i):

```
NSLog(@"%li",piecesOfOriginalString.count);
```

If you are asking: "what is the maximum number of elements that can be added to an NSArray," that question has been discussed here: [Maximum amount of objects in NSArray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155462/maximum-amount-of-objects-in-nsarray)

Answer (score 0):

I dont think there is such thing as a maximum array size, it's limited by free ram at execution point and array's content. You might need an mutable array (NSMutableArray) instead.

Maximum index value depends on the host computer harware and OS but usually it is at least 2^32-1, which is 4_294_967_295. Sometimes, when some strange people use signed indexes, it falls to 2^31-1, which is 2_147_483_647. Usually, considering that array items are in turn allocated in the dynamic memory, it is far more than your RAM can fit, so don't bother ;)

Comment: I believe cocoa defines the "sentinel value" `NSNotFound` as -1 (same bit pattern as highest possible unsigned long integer), so if (say) `-indexOfObject:` returns this value you can be 100% sure it is not a valid index and the object is not in the array. Even if the array had the maximum unsigned long integer value as `count`, the last index is one smaller so `NSNotFound` can never be a valid index. Correct me if I'm wrong...